# How can I list all words starting with "U_" in a directory containing source code

Tags: regex, linux, text

I need a linux command to look for all words starting with "U_" in some source code files and list them (the words). Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I answer myself:

```
cat *.sql | grep -o '\bU_\w*' | sort | uniq -c
```

This gives me all the coincidences of words starting with "U_" in the current directory in all files .sql.

The outputs looks like this:

```
  2 U_FVoucher1
  2 U_FVoucher2
  1 U_GrupoArticulo
  1 U_ImporteLetra
  1 U_ImporteNC
  4 U_ImportePagado
```

The number at the beginning is the total count for the coincidences in all files.

Hope this could help someone else.